# Flip and add margins to an SVG graphic

Tags: css, svg, vector-graphics

I want to create this svg grafic but can neither flip it nor make the white space appear on the top and the bottom. It just matches perfectly to the section above. I´m pretty new to svg so sry if this is a total noob question.

[How I want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMHMG.png)

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEk9K.png)

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container2">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <path d="M0,100 C490,200 350,0 1900,00 L500,00 L0,0 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:#21252917;"></path>
  </svg>


.container2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: you can also consider CSS solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try the use of a radial-gradient like below. It will also be responsive.

```css
.box {
  height:200px;
  padding:20px 0;
  background:
    radial-gradient(200% 200% at 50% 120%,transparent 27.5%,red 28%,red 58%,transparent 58.5%),
    radial-gradient(210% 140% at 50% 120%,transparent 27.5%,red 28%,red 58%,transparent 58.5%);
}


.phone {
  width:150px;
  height:100%;
  border-radius:10px;
  background:grey;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="phone"></div>
</div>
```

Adjust the percentage values to control the bottom and top curve:

```css
.box {
  --t1:200%;
  --t2:200%;
  --b1:210%;
  --b2:140%;
  height:200px;
  padding:20px 0;
  background:
    radial-gradient(var(--t1) var(--t2) at 50% 120%,transparent 27.5%,red 28%,red 58%,transparent 58.5%),
    radial-gradient(var(--b1) var(--b2) at 50% 120%,transparent 27.5%,red 28%,red 58%,transparent 58.5%);
}


.phone {
  width:150px;
  height:100%;
  border-radius:10px;
  background:grey;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--b1:250%;--b2:120%">
  <div class="phone"></div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="--t1:250%;--t2:180%">
  <div class="phone"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would have worked great except that it doesn´t work on mobile browsers and with safari unfortunately :/ Still looking for a svg path. I have this so far but it´s only half of what I want: M-1.97,86 C-1.41,86 250,-17 500,95 L501.97,2000 L-12.69,2000 Z